# Dragging linear layouts in linear layout for ordering

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

So what I'd like to achieve is the following.

I've got a LinearLayout full of several other LinearLayouts. So it is built up like a kind of List.

Now I want my users to be able to order the LinearLayouts that are inside of the main LinearLayout. It would be great if they could do this by a simple drag and drop system.

So here is a little picture of what I have and like to achieve:

http://image-upload.de/image/sHWFVI/a5a4aafc40.png

So that in this case let's say the first LinearLayout is called a) and the second b) and the third c).

In this case it is ordered like this:

a)
b)
c)

after he has dragged like the green arrow is pointing it should be ordered like this:

b)
a)
c)

Is there an easy way to achieve this or should I don't invest so much time in this feature? Because it would really be great if there was a way!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) by nhaarman is a simple library that allows you to do such things.

Take a look at the [Play Store Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations), it shows you how to create all sorts of animations for items in a list.

What you are looking for is the drag-and-drop animation (showcased [here](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulationexamples/DragAndDropActivity.java)), which allows you to customize what happens when a user rearranges the items in your list.

Comment: But the thing is that it is no ListView but just a LinearLayout

Comment: Seems to me you just need a listview with 3 items... On devices with enough screen space, it'll stay fixed, on others it'll scroll. If not, you need to  implement your own animation. Check out the source of this library, it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes but my first Problem is i don't know how to do the drag and drop system

Comment: Well you are going to have to look at what others have done so far. Look at the source of https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview -- it does only that. Can't help you much more if you aren't willing to look at other people's source. The goal of SO is not that I code it for you.

Comment: Okay yes thanks, I was just looking for an easy finished solution. But if there is none. Thank you for your help :)